# Casting error after jpa query on database

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

This query gives a array ob objects instead of giving me the Tracking object back.

In the log i see:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.quoka.qis.ads.web.tracking.Tracking

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "Tracking.findByNo", 
query = "select * " +
    "from inet.TRACKING t " +
    "where t.prditmNO = ?1"
)


TypedQuery<Tracking> q = em.createNamedQuery("Tracking.findByNo", Tracking.class);
q.setParameter(1, adno);
List<Tracking> list = q.getResultList();
return list.isEmpty()?null:list.get(0);
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a **native** query. You should use a **JPA** query.

```
 @NamedQuery( name = "Tracking.findByNo",  
              query = "select t " + 
                      "from Tracking t " +
                      "where t.prditmNO = ?1" )
```

Comment: I changed it and now I have:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Tracking.findByNo: select * from inet.TRACKING t where t.prditmNO = ?1], line 1, column 7: unexpected token [*].
It your example maybe a JSQL query and not a database query?

Comment: You didn't pay attention. NO __*__, use **'t'** instead of the *. Please read before writing.

Comment: Now I have got it. This sql statement has "nothing" to do with the database. It is pure based on the class and it's fields. Wow. Cool stuff! Thanks.